# Windows 8 Live Tile Update not working

Tags: windows-8, microsoft-metro, windows-runtime, live-tile

I'm writing a Windows 8 app and am trying to get live tiles working.  Here's what I have so far (all in `App.xaml.cs`):

In `OnLaunched()`:

```
Window.Current.VisibilityChanged += Current_VisibilityChanged;
```

The event handler for that:

```
void Current_VisibilityChanged(object sender, Windows.UI.Core.VisibilityChangedEventArgs e)
{
    // create a string with the tile template xml
    string tileXmlString = "<tile><visual><binding template=\"TileSquareBlock\">" + App.VM.GetImageLinks() + "</binding></visual></tile>";

    // create a DOM
    Windows.Data.Xml.Dom.XmlDocument tileDOM = new Windows.Data.Xml.Dom.XmlDocument();
    // load the xml string into the DOM, catching any invalid xml characters 
    tileDOM.LoadXml(tileXmlString);

    // create a tile notification
    TileNotification tile = new TileNotification(tileDOM);

    // send the notification to the app's application tile
    TileUpdateManager.CreateTileUpdaterForApplication().Update(tile);
}
```

`App.VM.GetImageLinks()` returns:

```
<tile>
    <visual>
        <binding template=\"TileSquareBlock\">
            <image id=\"1\">Assets/Img1.jpg</image>
            <image id=\"2\">Assets/Img2.jpg</image>
            <image id=\"3\">Assets/Img3.jpg</image>
        </binding>
    </visual>
</tile>
```

At the minute, I'm basically trying to just get these images to show on the start screen.  My guess is that `VisibilityChanged` is the wrong event, because it seems to occur too often.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The XML being used is invalid, as the TileSquareBlock template doesn't contain any images.  See the [tile template catalog](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/hh761491.aspx) to see the various visual templates and their corresponding XML.

The NotificationsExtensions library (found in the [MSDN tiles sample](http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsapps/App-tiles-and-badges-sample-5fc49148)) provides an object model that maps the image and text fields to named properties.  It provides more validation and may simplify your code.

Comment: yea I think he wants tileSquareImage